# Concatenar datos en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy recorriendo el valor de una etiqueta **select**
pero quiero concatenar los datos de la siguiente manera

```
codcli: ("5590541-2", "134054-9")
```

Este es mi código:

```
codcli='';

var val=document.getElementById('show_product');
for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
    if(val[i].selected){
        codcli += '(' + '"' + val[i].value + '",' + ')'; 
    }
}         
codcli=codcli.slice(0,codcli.length -1);
```

Al ejecutarlo, los datos me quedan de la siguiente manera que **no es** la que yo quiero:

```
codcli: ("5590541-2",)("134054-9",
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

El código no funciona por un problema de concatenación, como ya han señalado los compañeros.

A mi modo de ver, es mucho más simple guardar los valores en un array y luego sacar cada elemento del array separado por comas usando `join`.

Por ejemplo:

```
items=[];
var val=document.getElementById('show_product');
for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
    if(val[i].selected){
        items.push(val[i].value); 
    }
}         
var codcli=`("${items.join('","')}")`;
console.log(codcli);
```

---

Veamos una prueba real:

```js
var items=[];
/*Esto es lo que ocurriría en el for*/
items.push("5590541-2");
items.push("134054-9");

/*Variable final*/
var codcli=`("${items.join('","')}")`;

/*Prueba*/
console.log(codcli);
```

---

Esto

```
var codcli=`("${items.join('","')}")`
```

es porque según la pregunta quieres los valores entre comillas. Si quisieras los valores sin más sería más simple:

```
var codcli=`(${items.join()})`;
```

Y la salida sería:

```
(5590541-2,134054-9)
```

Por ejemplo:

```js
var items = [];
/*Esto es lo que ocurriría en el for*/
items.push("5590541-2");
items.push("134054-9");

/*Variable final*/
var codcli = `(${items.join()})`;

/*Prueba*/
console.log(codcli);
```

Answer (score 5):

Puedes simplemente ejecutar un `map` en la colección de `options` para obtener solo los valores. Luego, haciendo uso de `join` puedes concatenar cada valor de la colección usando un delimitador.

**Ejemplo**

```js
const products = document.querySelectorAll('#products > option')
const codes = Array.from(products).map(o => o.value)
const group = `(${codes.join(', ')})`
console.log(group)
```

```html
<select id="products">
  <option value="D484-7">Dell XPS 15</option>
  <option value="LT93-X">Lenovo Thinkpad T580</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Los paréntesis deberían ir afuera del for, no dentro. Al dejarlo dentro del bucle solo ocasionas que se repita siempre. Los paréntesis los agregas antes y después del for y ya te quedaría:

```
codcli='('; //inicializas la variable ya con un paréntesis

var val=document.getElementById('show_product');
for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
    if(val[i].selected){
        codcli += '"' + val[i].value + '",'; 
    }
}  
codcli += ')'; // aumentaría esta línea al final del for
```

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas concatenar los parentesis afuera del bucle asi:

```js
function concat() {

codcli='(';

var val=document.getElementById('show_product');
for (i=0;i< val.length;i++) { 
    if(val[i].selected){
        codcli += '"' + val[i].value + '",'; 
    }
}         
codcli=codcli.slice(0,codcli.length -1);
codcli+= ")";
console.log(codcli);
}
```

```html
<select id='show_product' multiple>
  <option value="5590541-2">5590541-2</option>
  <option value="134054-9">134054-9</option>
</select>

<button onClick="concat()">Concatenar</button>
```